# Sending SMS from Arduino MKR NB 1500 once triggered (gate opened)

Tags: arduino, sms

I have been trying to get an Arduino MKR NB 1500 to send an SMS once a gate is opened.
I have been using the **SendSMS** code in the Arduino IDE, and have looked at the **StateChangeDetection** codes.

I have got the Arduino to send an SMS VIA the Send SMS code, but not when it has been triggered.

***"When the current state of the sensor is changed, it needs to send an SMS, once it has been reset back to the original state, it needs to "reset" ready to send another one, again when opened..."***

Comment: It is not clear from your question what is not working. If you are able to send SMS in once condition but not in another, you should present all the details for those conditions, more specifically the code you are using. It is also unclear what is the quote you added, where it comes from nad what's the relevancy.

Comment: The quote is What I want to happen in the long run. I haven't been able to get it to send an SMS from the StateChangeDetection code (when the gate gets opened), I have only got it to happen when I do it on the computer. I am trying to somehow include the 2 sketches, so that once the state changes from OFF to ON or OPEN to CLOSED, the SMS will be sent.